# Update failed because of power failure, and I cannot open further

Tags: upgrade

I have tried to upgrade ubuntu 13.10 saucy to 14.04 Trusty Tahr, and somehow my laptop power failed, I failed to note where it stopped.

What are the things I can do, to debug it, and to fix it.

**What I have tried**

1. Boot
2. Select advanced mode
3. Select the top most option (with recovery), i think linux 3.24, something like that

**Result**

Fails to even boot, and gives me gibberish lines of text that I failed to note.

Comment: you should boot from a bootable pendrive backup data and do a fresh install!

Comment: fresh install? that will erase all my configuration and data?

Comment: Yeah it will erase all configuration but you can backup data!